# Pandas Newbie: Sort by nth row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Grouped     Week           Revenue        Users        Period   CSum
    2013-10-14  2013-10-14     2863.75           36             1   2863.75   
                2013-10-21      202.20            4             2   3065.95   
                2013-10-28      603.45            8             3   3669.40   
                2013-11-04      535.65            9             4   4205.05   
                2013-11-11      424.45           14             5   4629.50
    2015-06-01  2015-06-01    24115.91          468             1  24115.91   
                2015-06-08     1634.93           32             2  25750.84   
                2015-06-15     2664.00           62             3  28414.84   
                2015-06-22     1646.05           40             4  30060.89
```

Trying to figure out with Pandas how to essentially provide only the 4th Period for each Grouped so that I get:

```
    Grouped     Week           Revenue        Users        Period   CSum
    2013-10-14  2013-11-04      535.65            9             4   4205.05
    2015-06-01  2015-06-22     1646.05           40             4  30060.89
```

What would be the best method to do this?

Comment: Is Period a Series or part of the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Period'] == 4]
print (df)
                       Revenue  Users  Period      CSum
Grouped    Week                                        
2013-10-14 2013-11-04   535.65      9       4   4205.05
2015-06-01 2015-06-22  1646.05     40       4  30060.89
```

Another solution with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) if need select each `4.th` row per first level of `MultiIndex` and first solution cant be used:

```
ser = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
print (ser)
Grouped     Week      
2013-10-14  2013-10-14    0
            2013-10-21    1
            2013-10-28    2
            2013-11-04    3
            2013-11-11    4
2015-06-01  2015-06-01    0
            2015-06-08    1
            2015-06-15    2
            2015-06-22    3
dtype: int64

print (ser == 3)
Grouped     Week      
2013-10-14  2013-10-14    False
            2013-10-21    False
            2013-10-28    False
            2013-11-04     True
            2013-11-11    False
2015-06-01  2015-06-01    False
            2015-06-08    False
            2015-06-15    False
            2015-06-22     True
dtype: bool

print (df[ser == 3])
                       Revenue  Users  Period      CSum
Grouped    Week                                        
2013-10-14 2013-11-04   535.65      9       4   4205.05
2015-06-01 2015-06-22  1646.05     40       4  30060.89
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had tried boolean indexing too :) Next time i'll read the docs more!

Comment: Glad can help you!